# Adding Useragent information to prewritten script

Tags: php, android, redirect, tablet

I am using a prewritten mobile redirect script from http://code.google.com/p/php-mobile-detect/

I have seen several people say how it was the best.

It works on tablets and phones.

However my useragent is not listed in the script.

i dont know where to add it in this script to redirect this tablet model.

Could someone take a look and tell me how to add this useragent i would appreciate it `Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0; RCT6213W87DK Build/LRX21M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2490.76 Safari/537.36`

I'm not asking anyone to do this for me, but if someone could read the script and maybe explain what information i need to extract from my useragent and add to the script and where.

Currently my tablet is being recognized as a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a model of your tablet (Maven?) characterized uniquely by string "RCT6213W87DK" into $tabletDevices array inside the library: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect/blob/master/Mobile_Detect.php

Like so:

```
'MavenTablet' => 'RCT6213W87DK',
```